# Hide Query String In Php using .htaccess

Tags: php

I have This Type Of Url
http://www.localhost:82/frontend/productview?product_name=Purse

I Want To Hide Url And Look Like :
http://www.localhost:82/frontend/productview
There Is Any Way To Hide This Query String If Yes Then Please Give Me Solution.

Thanks In Advance.....

Comment: Sow us the code. And what does it have to do with MySQL?

Comment: What framework/webserver (configuration)? If you have a shorted URL where does the product_name=Purse get to the back end? While you could use `POST` requests `GET` requests are better because they are cacheable (client and reverse proxy side).

Comment: If you need the info that the product name is "Purse", then you need to have that information _somewhere_ in your URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ([^/]+)\.example\.com.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://www.localhost:82/frontend/productview [L]
```

Comment: I Am Finding Many Way And Spending Lots Of Hour For This ..Thank u So Much